# Опечатка в учебнике или нет? "не()обратима"

Tags: орфография

Добрый день! В учебнике по биологии за 8 класс, случайно наткнулась на описание смертей (биологическая и клиническая). И как сказано в учебнике, биологическая смерть "необратима". Скажите, правильно ли написано это слово, или же это опечатка? (Не обратима)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какова ваша точка зрения и на чём основана?

Answer (score 7):

Необратима - краткое прилагательное, слитно пишется, потому что полная форма пишется слитно - необратимая. Прилагательные на -мый, образованные от глаголов сов. вида(обратить) или непереходных, с частицей НЕ пишутся слитно, если нет пояснительных слов-отрицательных местоимений и наречий, начинающихся с НИ, или сочетаний далеко не, вовсе не, отнюдь не.

Вот если бы это было слово на -мый, образованное от переходных глаголов несов. вида,тогда бы оно могло быть и причастием, если бы при нём было зависимое слово в творит. падеже.А краткое причастие писалось бы с НЕ раздельно.

Answer (score 0):

Да, орфография соответствует правилам. "Не" с кратким прилагательным пишется слитно, если образует новое качество. Здесь как раз такой случай. *Необратимый* означает не отрицание некоей "обратимости", а вполне цельное понятие.